# Is off-heap cache DirectMemory ready for production? Is it active?

Tags: java, caching, directmemory

DirectMemory seems to be the only open source off-heap cache for Java.

Is it ready for production?

Is it an active, viable project? I looked at its mailing list archive and it's very low volume.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using direct memory in production for a few years.  It was first introduced in Java 1.4 in 2002.

I have also been using memory mapped files more recently to support shared memory between processes and data sizes much larger than the swap space.  Direct memory is often more limited to the physical memory size as many systems don't have much swap space these days.

The underlying calls used are *very* old and use in most C and C++ applications, possibly dating back as far as the 70's.

I didn't know there was a direct memory mailing list. I couldn't find it using google.  Perhaps its hard to find so that why people don't use it so much.

Comment: I think the OP's talking about [this particular incubating Apache project](http://incubator.apache.org/directmemory/) which uses what you're talking about and has a [mailing-list](http://incubator-directmemory-user.markmail.org/)

Comment: In that case, I would ask the question on the mailing list for that product.  The fact its still in the incubator section and is version 0.5.5-SNAPSHOT suggests its not quite production ready.